# is it possible to put after effects on html5?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, after-effects

good day

is it possible to put after effects on html5?

im planning to have a photo booth with live praps for example on my background is wild and then there is a tiger moving around while your having picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you’re asking ?!

Canvas is quick enough to let you play video on the canvas and then draw a person’s picture on top of the moving video.

Here is some example code showing how to draw video into a canvas.

Then you would use the same canvas context to add a person’s photo to the video.

The effect is like having the weatherman "green screened" on top of the weather map.

```
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<video id=v controls loop>
    <source src=video.webm type=video/webm>
    <source src=video.ogg type=video/ogg>
    <source src=video.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var video = document.getElementById('v');
        var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 100);
        var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 100);
        canvas.width = cw;
        canvas.height = ch;

        video.addEventListener('play', function(){
            draw(this,context,cw,ch);
        },false);

    },false);

    function draw(video,canvasContext,w,h) {
        if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
        c.drawImage(video,0,0,w,h);
        setTimeout(draw,20,video,canvasContext,w,h);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is it possible to make the video transparent? one of my concern is how im gonna put a tiger that moves around while im taking pictures.

Comment: Probably, yes.  Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do...I'm unclear.